# C pthreads Mutex not working as expected

Tags: multithreading, mutex

```
void *printing(void*);
pthread_mutex_t lock;

int main()
{
    pthread_t thrA,thrB,thrC;
    int num1=1,num2=2,num3=3;

    pthread_create(&thrA, NULL,*printing,(void*)num1 );
    pthread_create(&thrB, NULL,*printing, (void*)num2);
    pthread_create(&thrC, NULL,*printing, (void*)num3);

    pthread_join(thrA,NULL);
    pthread_join(thrB,NULL);
    pthread_join(thrC,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy (&lock);

    return 0;
}

void *printing(void*param)
{

    int *num; //int pointer to receive void pass
    num = (int *) param; //assign void array to int array


    int k;
    for (k=0; k<3; k++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&lock);
        sleep((rand() % 10)/10);
        printf("%d",num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        printf("  ");
    }


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

the output that i get is  2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 or sometimes 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 3 or 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2
but i want the order always to be 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
the code sleeps some random time in the protected part (mutex lock) so that the next thread print its number during that time.
where is the problem? how can i control which thread runs first?

Answer (score 2):

```
int k;
for (k=0; k<3; k++)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&lock);
    sleep((rand() % 10)/10);
    printf("%d",num);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("  ");
}
```

There are two problems here.

1. as soon as you spawn the threads, there are no way to know when, or even in which order they are going to be scheduled on a CPU, the system scheduler is free to do whatever it considers to be the best option. So there is **no guarantee** that thread with `num = 1` will be the first one to be scheduled.
2. your sleep() call is in the critical section (i.e. between locking and unlocking), so the threads sleep while holding the mutex, making the sleep virtually useless because other threads cannot do anything during the sleep time. Once the mutex is finally released by the thread, the same thread loops and almost immediately call pthread_mutex_lock() again.

Please note that mutexes are not really meant for controlling thread execution order, they're meant to protect multiple threads to access the same variable at the same time. Condition variables or semaphores may be appropriate for what you're trying to do.

You might also want to use `printf("%d\n",num)` (i.e. add newline) since I/Os are buffered on most systems. Although it shouldn't be a problem here, it can create some confusion if you're trying to understand what's going on.

Here something that works for me (except that the first thread is not necessarily the first (see 1.))

```
for (k=0; k<3; k++)
{
  sleep(1); 
  pthread_mutex_lock (&lock);
  printf("%d\n",num);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Output: 
  2
  1
  3
  2
  1
  3
  2
  1
  3

Once again, this isn't guaranteed;

Answer (score 0):

The first thread created runs and gets the lock on the mutex, sleeps, writes 1 and then unlocks the mutex.

Output: 1

Before the first thread unlocks the mutex, the other two threads run and wait for the mutex to be unlocked.

Immediately after the first thread unlocks the mutex, one of the other two threads waiting for the mutex can acquire the lock.   In your case, thread 2 gets the lock, probably as it was the first to begin waiting for the mutex, but the order in which waiting threads acquire a lock is not guaranteed, see [Order of execution of waiting threads blocked by mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545129/order-of-execution-of-waiting-threads-blocked-by-mutex)

So, thread number 2 gets the lock, sleeps, writes 1 and unlocks the mutex.

Output: 1 1

In the meantime, thread 1 returns to the start of the loop and waits for the mutex lock.

Immediately after the second thread unlocks the mutex, one of the other two threads waiting for the lock (1 and 3) can acquire it.   In your case, thread 3 got the lock.

So, thread number 3 gets the lock, sleeps, writes 1 and unlocks the mutex.

Output: 1 1 1

And so on and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, either I'm missing something or your question is wrong. You suggest "the code sleeps some random time in the protected part (mutex lock) so that the next thread print its number during that time" and say that you thus expect "1 2 3 ...". This is contradictory, if each thread waited for the others, they would take turns and print "1 1 1 2 2 2 ..." as you said is what you got. (But that's **not** really the reason.)

Secondly, you seem to be confused on how mutexes work. SlappyTheFish explained that pretty well so I guess I needn't bother. However I'm not sure if the behavior explained by SlappyTheFish is *guaranteed*, even though it's exactly what you got in your test and would probably happen in pretty much all cases in practice, but when you use threads you should actually see them as entirely separate computations which *actually might not even run in parallel*. Only when a certain thread blocks and waits for something in the other threads to happen is it guaranteed that that thread will run and finish its job which is being waited for. Optimizing compilers and complicated CPUs can do pretty crazy things to the *exact* order of execution between your threads so you can never rely on any behavior unless you explicitly use synchronization mechanisms. If I'm not mistaken, it could as well happen that the first thread gets the mutex three times in a row, before other threads ever get it. Your code does not explicitly specify anything that forbids this.